# AngularJS use parent directive to handle child directive's action

Tags: angularjs

I have a pretty simple directive, which basically contains child directives, which each call a function when clicked.

```
<yd-chart-selector>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="column" on-click="main.drawColumnChart()"></yd-chart-selector-item>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="web" on-click="main.drawSpiderChart()"></yd-chart-selector-item>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="line" on-click="main.drawLineChart()"></yd-chart-selector-item>
</yd-chart-selector>
```

getting this directive to work in it's simplest form, ie clicking an item calls the method, was simple to do.

i also wanted to set the clicked `yd-chart-selector-item` to active. again, doing that was simple, using a property on my VM.

however, when I set an item to active, the other items should become inactive.

so I figured that I would maintain a list of items on the parent, and use the parent to handle invoking the actions, and clearing the active of the items in it's list.

I have got this working, but it doesnt feel right to me.

```
app.directive('ydChartSelector', chartSelector);

function chartSelector() {
    var directive = {
        template: '<div class="form-group graph-type-select pull-right" ng-transclude=""></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: true,
        link: link,
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        transclude: true
    };
    return directive;

    function controller() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.items = [];

        vm.addItem = addItem;
        vm.selectItem = selectItem;

        function addItem(item) {
            vm.items.push(item);

            if(vm.items.length === 1) {
                item.selected = true;
            }
        }

        function selectItem(item) {
            resetUi(vm);
            item.selected = true;
            item.onClick();
        }

    }

    function resetUi(vm) {
        vm.items.forEach(function(value) {
            value.selected = false;
        });
    }

}

app.directive('ydChartSelectorItem', chartSelectorItem);

function chartSelectorItem() {
    var directive = {
        template: '<button type="button" class="btn graph-type-btn" ng-class="[vm.buttonClass, {selected: vm.selected}]" ng-click="vm.f(this)"></button>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        require: '^ydChartSelector',
        scope: {
            onClick: '@',
            buttonClass: '@'
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, chartSelectorController) {
        chartSelectorController.addItem(scope.vm);
    }

    function controller() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.selected = false;
        vm.f = f;

        function f($scope) {
            $scope.$parent.$parent.vm.selectItem(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

the part that is bugging me is:

```
function f($scope) {
    $scope.$parent.$parent.vm.selectItem(vm);
}
```

there must be a better way to do this?

I tried using `'&'` and `'@'` combinations for trying to bind to the parent, but could not get it right.

Comment: if you are passing a function (`onClick`), then you definitely need to use `&` and not `=`

Comment: thanks, I have changed that

Answer (score 0):

You should use isolated scope with `&` for passing method to directive & method should have `on-click="main.drawLineChart()"` function bracket so that the method will get call, Inside you controller you could call `vm.onClick()` to call method of directive element.

```
scope: {
    onClick: '&',
    buttonClass: '@'
}
```

**Markup**

```
<yd-chart-selector>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="column" on-click="main.drawColumnChart">
    </yd-chart-selector-item>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="web" on-click="main.drawSpiderChart()">
    </yd-chart-selector-item>
    <yd-chart-selector-item button-class="line" on-click="main.drawLineChart()">
    </yd-chart-selector-item>
</yd-chart-selector>
```